# Sort a vector in which the n first elements have been already sorted?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, vector

Consider a `std::vector` `v` of `N` elements, and consider that the `n` first elements have already been sorted with`n < N` and where `(N-n)/N` is very small:

[image: sorted/unsorted vector]

Is there a clever way using the STL algorithms to sort this vector more rapidly than with a complete `std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v))` ?

EDIT: a clarification: the (N-n) unsorted elements should be inserted at the right position within the n first elements already sorted.

EDIT2: bonus question: and how to find n ? (which corresponds to the first unsorted element)

Comment: The answer to EDIT2 is [`std::is_sorted_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until)

Comment: Is doing it in-place a requirement? It seems to be implied, but you do not say it explicitly.

Comment: If `N-m` is small, then you can use insertion sort. Yes, it is considered as a bad sorting algorithm, but the fact is that it is efficient when the input is almost sorted. Alternatively if you can spare a bit of extra memory, you can move the unsorted elements into  a different vector, sort it and do a merge sort, in which case you might want to sort from the end rather than the beginning.

Comment: What's the problem with std::sort? You don't have to provide the iterator to the starting element. You might as well provide iterator to 200th element (as in `vec.begin() + 199`)

Comment: C++ stdlib doesn't has some adaptive sorting algorithms available? (e.g. timsort) Otherwise you could just use those to sort the whole array and the algorithm would automatically avoid to waste time in the first part.

Comment: Consider [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Comment: I commented that this question should be closed and even downvoted, because it clearly does not show any attempt to solve a trivial question, but for some reason my comment was deleted. So trying one more time: based on [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) Do not ask "questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: The important question, which you've somewhat answered in the negative in your EDIT2, is "Is n known or not?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
void foo( std::vector<int> & tab, int n ) {
     std::sort( begin(tab)+n, end(tab));
     std::inplace_merge(begin(tab), begin(tab)+n, end(tab));
}
```

for edit 2

```
auto it = std::adjacent_find(begin(tab), end(tab),  std::greater<int>() );
if (it!=end(tab)) {
    it++;
    std::sort( it, end(tab));
    std::inplace_merge(begin(tab), it, end(tab));
}
```

Comment: I added a question (see EDIT 2)

Comment: @Vincent you should open a new question then, anyway, here your answer for this time

Comment: You could use [`std::is_sorted_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until) instead of that `std::adjacent_find`

Comment: Again, standard `inplace_merge` is formally a "fake", "simulated" in-place merge. The standard allows it to work out-of-place and allows it to perform a full sort. Frankly, I don't remember ever seeing a single honest implementation that is in-place and is not a full sort. The algorithm is too complicated to bother. If you know one, please tell me.

Answer (score 23):

Sort the other range only, and then use [std::merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge).

Comment: merge need separated input and output, the correct algorithm to use is `inplace_merge` here.

Comment: I know, but the OP didn't tell if he wanted to have it in place.

Comment: While your post is not a classical case of link-only answer, because it contains at least a name of a function, that's still only a bit above the threashold. Please provide at least a minimalistic usage example, at best connected with OPs problem. I know this was upvoted by many people, but would they upvote too, if the link was removed?

Answer (score 8):

The optimal solution would be to sort the tail portion independently and then perform in-place merge, as described here

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.5750

The algorithm is quite convoluted and is usually regarded as "not worth the effort".

Of course, with C++ you can use readily available `std::inplace_merge`. However, the name of that algorithm is highly misleading. Firstly, there's no guarantee that `std::inplace_merge` actually works in-place. And when it is actually in-place, there's no guarantee that it is not implemented as a full-blown sort. In practice it boils down to trying it and seeing whether it is good enough for your purposes.

But if you really want to make it in-place and formally more efficient than a full sort, then you will have to implement it manually. STL might help with a few utility algorithms, but it does not offer any solid solutions of "just a few calls to standard functions" kind.

Comment: From the complexity bounds given in the Standard, it seems that a conforming `inplace_merge` is not even allowed to use the optimal algorithm, which is considerably more expensive than the naive approach in terms of comparisons performed. But then of course the naive approach requires allocation of a temporary buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Using insertion sort on `N - n` last elements:

```
template <typename IT>
void mysort(IT begin, IT end) {
    for (IT it = std::is_sorted_until(begin, end); it != end; ++it) {
        IT insertPos = std::lower_bound(begin, it, *it);
        IT endRotate = it;
        std::rotate(insertPos, it, ++endRotate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) sorting algorithm is a hybrid algorithm developed by Pythonista Tim Peters.  It makes optimal use of already-sorted subsegments *anywhere* inside the array, including in the beginning.  Although you may find a faster algorithm if you know for sure that in particular *the first* n elements are already sorted, this algorithm should be useful for the overall class of problems involved.  Wikipedia describes it as:

> The algorithm finds subsets of the data that are already ordered, and uses that knowledge to sort the remainder more efficiently.

In Tim Peters' own words,

> It has supernatural performance on many
>   kinds of partially ordered arrays (less than lg(N!) comparisons needed, and
>   as few as N-1), yet as fast as Python's previous highly tuned samplesort
>   hybrid on random arrays.

Full details are described [in this undated text document by Tim Peters](http://bugs.python.org/file4451/timsort.txt).  The examples are in Python, but Python should be quite readable even to people not familiar with its syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::partition_point (or is_sorted_until) to find n. Then if n-m is small do an insertion sort (linear search+std::rotate).

Comment: It is expected to elaborate a bit more on SO. Please provide at least single-line use example, at best so that it would pass to OPs code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your question has two aims:

- improve runtime (using a clever way)
- with few effort (restricting to STL)

Considering these aims, I'd strongly recommend against this specific optimization, unless you are sure that the effort is worth the benefit.
As far as I remember, std::sort() implements the quick sort algorithm, which is almost as fast on presorted input as to determine, if / how-much-of the input is sorted.

Instead of meddling with std::sort you can try changing the data structure to a sorted/prioritized queue.

Comment: Quicksort is not fast on pre-sorted input. It may be *very slow*, for certain choices of pivot (unlikely in modern implementations), but the best-case performance of quicksort is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: You're right. In fact, I messed up: Sorted data can be the worst case for quicksort (depending on an unlikely choice of pivot). However, if the data is always sorted but for the last few appended elements, there is **no** need to check the first elements. You can simply have the data structure sort the last elements, when appending them. In this I assume that the vector is build up successively, because that's how a situation like this typically occurs.